Checking if a graph is bipartite
Lets say I'm given n nodes labeled 0 to n-1 and a list of edges. I understand that the typical solution for detecting bipartite graphs is to do bfs or dfs. I took a different approach by iterating through the edges and adding each edge to either a 0 set or a 1 set. The idea is that if an edge connects any 2 vertices that are in the same set, the graph is not bipartite.
For some reason, my code does not work on a certain test case in the platform I am using but the test is 10000 vertices so its near impossible to debug. My code is returning False when the answer is True. I don't see anyone online using the same idea I have, so I'd like to understand why from a theoretical standpoint my code would not work.
def is_bipartite(n, edges):
    """
    Args:
     n(int32)
     edges(list_list_int32)
    Returns:
     bool
    """
    s = [-1 for _ in range(n)]
    
    for u, v in edges:
        if s[u] > -1 and s[u] == s[v]:
            return False
        if s[u] > -1 and s[v] == -1:
            s[v] =  1 - s[u]
        elif s[u] == -1 and s[v] > -1:
            s[u] =  1 - s[v]
        elif s[u] == -1 and s[v] == -1:
            s[u] = 0
            s[v] = 1
    
    return True

```


The problem is due to the last case, where you arbitrarily put $u$ in the set $V_0$ (vertices labelled with $0$) and $v$ in the set $V_1$.
Imagine the following graph:
0--2--3--1

Consider you are checking edges in this order: $\{0,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{2,3\}$.
Your algorithm could arbitrarily put $0$ in $V_0$, $2$ in $V_1$, then put $1$ in $V_0$ and $3$ in $V_1$, then detect a contradiction while checking $\{2,3\}$. However the graph is actually bipartite (since it has no cycle).
The usual way to check bipartition is similar to your idea, but you have to consider edges in a specific order for it to work. This is usually done with a graph traversal: for each connected component, you put arbitrarily the first vertex in $V_0$, then you check each reachable edge in the right order (either BFS or DFS, or any other traversal work).

Thanks, that explains it
